# filter array of objects by array of values es6

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

i need a help to do a function to filter an array of object by an a array with values, example:

my array with objects:

```html
const persons = [
  {
    personId: 1,
    name: 'Patrick',
    lastName: 'Smith',
    age: 27,
    allergy: [
    {
      idAllergy: 1,
      name: 'Fish'
    },{
      idAllergy: 2,
      name: 'Nuts'
    }
    ]
  },
  {
    personId: 2,
    name: 'Lara',
    lastName: 'Blake',
    age: 21,
    allergy: [
    {
      idAllergy: 2,
      name: 'Nuts'
    }
    ]
  },
  {
    personId: 3,
    name: 'Erick',
    lastName: 'Robinson',
    age: 30,
    allergy: [
    {
      idAllergy: 3,
      name: 'Flowers'
    }
    ]
  },
  {
    personId: 4,
    name: 'Hilda',
    lastName: 'Vianne',
    age: 35,
    allergy: [
    {
      idAllergy: 4,
      name: 'Chocolat'
    }
    ]
  }

]
```

my array with values to filter:

// these are idAllergy
let allergy = [2,3]

so the plan is use allergy array values to seach into persons for people who has allergy to nuts and flowers and dont show them so my expected result will be:

```
 [{
    personId: 4,
    name: 'Hilda',
    lastName: 'Vianne',
    age: 35,
    allergy: [
    {
      idAllergy: 4,
      name: 'Chocolat'
    }
    ]
  }]
```

thanks in advance

Comment: is this the id of the allergy ? [2,3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const filtered = persons.filter(p => !p.allergy.some(a => allergy.includes(a.idAllergy)));
```

```js
const persons = [
    {
        personId: 1,
        name: 'Patrick',
        lastName: 'Smith',
        age: 27,
        allergy: [
            {
                idAllergy: 1,
                name: 'Fish'
            },{
                idAllergy: 2,
                name: 'Nuts'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        personId: 2,
        name: 'Lara',
        lastName: 'Blake',
        age: 21,
        allergy: [
            {
                idAllergy: 2,
                name: 'Nuts'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        personId: 3,
        name: 'Erick',
        lastName: 'Robinson',
        age: 30,
        allergy: [
            {
                idAllergy: 3,
                name: 'Flowers'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        personId: 4,
        name: 'Hilda',
        lastName: 'Vianne',
        age: 35,
        allergy: [
            {
                idAllergy: 4,
                name: 'Chocolat'
            }
        ]
    }

]


let allergy = [2,3]

const filtered = persons.filter(p => !p.allergy.some(a => allergy.includes(a.idAllergy)));

console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want people with the allergy 2 and 3 do this:

```
let allergy = [2,3];
const personsWithAllergy = persons.filter(
   p => p.allergy.some(al => allergy.includes(al.idAllergy)));
```

```js
const persons = [
    {
        personId: 1,
        name: 'Patrick',
        lastName: 'Smith',
        age: 27,
        allergy: [
            {
                idAllergy: 1,
                name: 'Fish'
            },{
                idAllergy: 2,
                name: 'Nuts'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        personId: 2,
        name: 'Lara',
        lastName: 'Blake',
        age: 21,
        allergy: [
            {
                idAllergy: 2,
                name: 'Nuts'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        personId: 3,
        name: 'Erick',
        lastName: 'Robinson',
        age: 30,
        allergy: [
            {
                idAllergy: 3,
                name: 'Flowers'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        personId: 4,
        name: 'Hilda',
        lastName: 'Vianne',
        age: 35,
        allergy: [
            {
                idAllergy: 4,
                name: 'Chocolat'
            }
        ]
    }

]


const allergy = [2,3];
const personsWithAllergy = persons.filter(p => p.allergy.some(al => allergy.includes(al.idAllergy)));

console.log(personsWithAllergy);
```

Answer (score 1):

basically using `filter` and `some` will do the trick!

```js
const persons = [{
    personId: 1,
    name: 'Patrick',
    lastName: 'Smith',
    age: 27,
    allergy: [{
      idAllergy: 1,
      name: 'Fish'
    }, {
      idAllergy: 2,
      name: 'Nuts'
    }]
  },
  {
    personId: 2,
    name: 'Lara',
    lastName: 'Blake',
    age: 21,
    allergy: [{
      idAllergy: 2,
      name: 'Nuts'
    }]
  },
  {
    personId: 3,
    name: 'Erick',
    lastName: 'Robinson',
    age: 30,
    allergy: [{
      idAllergy: 3,
      name: 'Flowers'
    }]
  },
  {
    personId: 4,
    name: 'Hilda',
    lastName: 'Vianne',
    age: 35,
    allergy: [{
      idAllergy: 4,
      name: 'Chocolat'
    }]
  }

]

const allergies = [2, 3]

const resultWithAllergies = persons.filter(person => {
  const {
    allergy
  } = person;

  const hasAllergy = allergy.some(({
    idAllergy
  }) => allergies.includes(idAllergy))

  return hasAllergy;
})


console.log(resultWithAllergies)
```

```js
const persons = [{
    personId: 1,
    name: 'Patrick',
    lastName: 'Smith',
    age: 27,
    allergy: [{
      idAllergy: 1,
      name: 'Fish'
    }, {
      idAllergy: 2,
      name: 'Nuts'
    }]
  },
  {
    personId: 2,
    name: 'Lara',
    lastName: 'Blake',
    age: 21,
    allergy: [{
      idAllergy: 2,
      name: 'Nuts'
    }]
  },
  {
    personId: 3,
    name: 'Erick',
    lastName: 'Robinson',
    age: 30,
    allergy: [{
      idAllergy: 3,
      name: 'Flowers'
    }]
  },
  {
    personId: 4,
    name: 'Hilda',
    lastName: 'Vianne',
    age: 35,
    allergy: [{
      idAllergy: 4,
      name: 'Chocolat'
    }]
  }

]

const allergies = [2, 3];

const resultWithoutAllergies = persons.filter(person => {
  const {
    allergy
  } = person;

  const hasAllergy = allergy.some(({
    idAllergy
  }) => !allergies.includes(idAllergy))

  return hasAllergy;
})
console.log(resultWithoutAllergies)
```